# Nodejs String split by \n but not \\n

Tags: javascript, node.js, split

In my node.js program, I have a string like this

```
var body = "i am a bog\n not girl\\n hahaha";
```

I want to split by `\n` but don't split `\\n`.
I am currently doing this

```
body.split("\\n")
```

But is it not working, how can I split `\n` but not `\\n`.

Thanks

Comment: if you want to split on `\n` split on `\n` ... splitting in `\\n` splits on `\\n` - it's not rocket surgery

Comment: try, splitting by simple regExp, `body.split(/\n/);`

Comment: because i split on \n, \\n will spilt too

Comment: have you checked it, I added reexp, not string, please check in console. `body.split(/\n/);`

Comment: @JeffLee, have you tried now?

Comment: just write "\n" not "\\n"

Comment: tried to use \\n work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above, you have used

> body.split("\\n")

This mean split the string into sub strings based on the given string i.e \n

As a result, we can see the result as

> [ 'i am a bog\n not girl', ' hahaha' ]

which is not your intention.
So, use

> body.split("\n")

which splits with respect to the string \n and produces result as

> [ 'i am a bog', ' not girl\n hahaha' ]

Answer (score 0):

You have a weird string, but using `\n` in the regex

```js
var body1 = "i am a bog\n not girl\\n hahaha";
console.log('body1', body1.split(/\n/));

var body2 = "lorum ipsum \n dun split \\n while \n must be split...";
console.log('body2', body2.split(/\n/));
```

should do the job.

EDIT: I have checked it on Node's CLI to ensure that it works there too.

```
> let a = "i am a bog\n not girl\\n hahaha";
undefined
> a
'i am a bog\n not girl\\n hahaha'
> a.split(/\n/);
[ 'i am a bog', ' not girl\\n hahaha' ]
>
```

As you can see, it works there too.

Comment: this is the same thing I added in the comment.

Comment: @siam because Chrome's console treats the string differently. `\n` becomes literally a new line, denoted as `↵`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tried using **`body.split("\\n")` it is obviously wrong.**

According to your question, you should first try,

**`body.split("\n")`**

The best way to split is using a regular expression.

**`body.split(/\n/)`** ---> This code finds `/n` in the string and splits it.

```js
var body1 = "i am a bog\n not girl\\n hahaha";
console.log('body1', body1.split(/\n/));
console.log('body1', body1.split("\n"));
```

[**Open this URL and you will get the same in NODE EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT and you can try many examples**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcWQzdWEtNGpTN3c)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
```

Comment: you should also explain what this regex is doing !